# Find Unique Values Across Data Frames without looping

Tags: python, pandas

How do I find unique values across Data Frames without looping?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,105673,size=100).reshape(10,10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,206782,size=100).reshape(10,10))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,435612,size=100).reshape(10,10))
```

To find the unique values for only one Data Frame I've used `pd.unique(df1.values.ravel())`. While looping through the Data Frames, using a list to append the unique values throws a memory error (The range mentioned in df1, df2, df3 is just an example. The actual range could be millions). How do I handle this?

Comment: Usually when you have a list of homogenous dataframes you probably want just one big dataframe with a multilevel index.

Comment: @U2EF1 The problem with one big Data Frame is memory. Thats the reason I have them as chunks.

Comment: how big are we talking? if everything fits in memory (in chunks or monolithically) i would imagine 1 dataframe is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the unique values in a dataframe `df` by converting its flattened values to a set `set(df.values.ravel())` (in the set data structure duplicate values will automatically be removed).

Comment: Or use a set union. If si is set(dfi.values.ravel()) then the set of unique values in df1, df2, df3 would be s1 | s2 | s3